# How to send an object of another class to itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, mvvm

I am very new to WPF and couldn't get my head around this so checked couple tutorials and kinda merged them together and I am here with this mess. Dont really know how should I describe my issue around so I decided to write here.

What I am working on;

Using a WPF I got a menu opening UserControls inside the Main Window.
When Main Window starts I am starting a thread like this so I get a loop

```
private void MainLoop()
{
    Thread th = Thread.CurrentThread;
    while (th.ThreadState != ThreadState.AbortRequested &&
        th.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted)
    {
        if (bMainOk)
        {
            switch (activeUC)
            {
                case "ucDurum":
                    LoopControl.ucDurumLoop(plc, connectionString);
                    break;
                case "ucAyarlar":
                    //LoopControl.ucAyarlarLoop();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

That LoopControl class has functions inside that are looping depending on the active UserControl.

```
public class LoopControl : ObservableObject
{
    public static void ucDurumLoop(ActUtlType plc, string connectionString)
    {
        DurumVM durum = new DurumVM();

        // The values do change before this lines, I didnt put them for the sake of clarity
        durum.RaporAktif = "true";
        durum.RaporAdedi = arrayData[0].ToString();
        durum.BufferPercent = "%" + (float)arrayData[0] / 250 * 100;
        durum.PlcSonCounter = arrayData[4].ToString();
        durum.SqlSonCounter = sonCntr.ToString();
    }
}
```

Which is Connected to a Main ViewModel then sub ViewModels like so

```
class MainVM
{
    public DurumVM Durum { get; private set; }
    public AyarlarVM Ayarlar { get; private set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Durum = new DurumVM();
        Ayarlar = new AyarlarVM();
    }
}
```

```
public class DurumVM : ObservableObject
{
    #region PLCVars
    private bool _raporAktif;
    private string _raporAdedi;
    private string _bufferPercent;
    private string _plcSonCounter;
    private string _sqlSonCounter;
    #endregion

    #region PLCGetSets
    public string RaporAktif
    {
        get
        {
            if (_raporAktif)
                return "Düzenlenecek True";

            return "Düzenlenecek False";
        }
        set
        {
            _raporAktif = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            OnPropertyChanged("RaporAktif");
        }
    }
    public string RaporAdedi
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_raporAdedi))
                return "Zeroh";

            return _raporAdedi;
        }
        set
        {
            _raporAdedi = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RaporAdedi");
        }
    }
    public string BufferPercent
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bufferPercent))
                return "%0";

            return _bufferPercent;
        }
        set
        {
            _bufferPercent = (value.Length <= 5 ? value : value.Substring(0, 5));
            OnPropertyChanged("BufferPercent");
        }
    }
    public string PlcSonCounter
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_plcSonCounter))
                return "0";

            return _plcSonCounter;
        }
        set
        {
            _plcSonCounter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PlcSonCounter");
        }
    }
    public string SqlSonCounter
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sqlSonCounter))
                return "0";

            return _sqlSonCounter;
        }
        set
        {
            _sqlSonCounter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SqlSonCounter");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the user control are bound to these values:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="Aktif mi? :" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RaporAktif, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,25,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
...
```

```
public partial class ucDurum : UserControl
{
    MainVM viewModel = new MainVM();

    //LoopControl viewModel = new LoopControl();
    public ucDurum()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = viewModel.Durum;
        Control.activeUC = "ucDurum";
    }
}
```

Quick sum:
I got set of user controls and one main loop. Main loop has parts that only works if correct user control is active, connects to somewhere else and gets values then *sets these values on a reference, sends it to user control and textblocks the values bound will update*

What is wrong that I know:
Practice might be very incorrect. It was looking good in my head but I realized the problem. Mainly due to my lack of C#  knowledge. The main loop gets reference of VM sets the datas but never sends them anywhere as I bolded in quick summary. I certain the problem is there since the values I got are correct, when I change values view button etc they do change and update. But VM has no idea about LoopControl.

In MVC I'd return the referenced object then get values on view. In here the values are bound directly and I am kind of lost.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough above the last paragraphs.

What I expect it to do:
LoopControl.ucDurumLoop updates DurumVM using referenced object so the user control "ucDurum" can see it and update TextBlock values accordingly.

[image: FlowChart]

What is happening:
I set up the referenced object in LoopControl.ucDurumLoop with the values but that is just an object and stays there. Doesn't go to DurumVM and update values using their Get/Set 's, so values are same and user control "ucDurum" has no idea what is going on on LoopControl.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: It is totally unclear what the code is supposed to do. Be aware that `Thread.CurrentThread` does not start a Thread. You should however not start any threads at all. If you need to do something cyclically, use a DispatcherTimer. But even that seems unnecessary. The whole idea of a "main loop" does not make sense. A UI application already has such a loop built-in to dispatch events to its components. Perhaps you just want to react on the Click event of a MenuItem.

Comment: We need to know what you *expect* should happen and what is actually happening. What *isn't working* as intended?

Comment: Updated the question with an expectance and what is happening.
I thought the summary at the end was clear enough but English isn't my native sorry about it.

Comment: @DekuDesu Basically LoopControl.ucDurumLoop can't update DurumVM variables.

Comment: @Ethen.S A loop checking values and updates variables which are bound to a UserControl TextBlock.Text

Comment: @Clemens I know the thread.Start() is on window load event. When clicked on MenuItem it loads the UserControl to a grid. Then also changes activeUC variable to a name that Switch-Case can use to decide which part of loop it should loop. So the values can update like every 2 seconds that loop reads from somewhere else outside of the application.
I already get the values, loop working perfectly, just cannot update the viewmodel variables from the loop and since variables doesn't change values on UserControl TextBlocks doesn't change either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was being stupid.

Problem was, I was creating new object reference and updating it while I had to reference the one on UserControl.

All I needed was changing a line in LoopControl

```cs
public class LoopControl : ObservableObject
{
    public static void ucDurumLoop(ActUtlType plc, string connectionString)
    {
        DurumVM durum = new DurumVM(); // Changing this
        DurumVM durum = ucDurum.viewModel; // To this.

        durum.RaporAktif = "true";
        durum.RaporAdedi = arrayData[0].ToString();
        durum.BufferPercent = "%" + (float)arrayData[0] / 250 * 100;
        durum.PlcSonCounter = arrayData[4].ToString();
        durum.SqlSonCounter = sonCntr.ToString();
    }
}
```